# Как лучше реализовать каталог на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

**Здравствуйте.**
Есть каталог на сайте, написан на фреймворке бутстрап 4

Всего 1 ряда, 4 колонки - 8 позиций товаров.

Внизу под этим всем нужно добавить 4 кнопки навигации, [[1]]-активная [2] [3] [4]

**Все это нужно реализовать так чтобы при нажатии на [2] [3] [4], страница не перезагружалась.**

Что лучше использовать в решении этого вопроса ?
На прошлом проекте были tabs (какой-то плагин, не помню точно) вот пример кода -

```html
<ul id="tabs-menu">
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Портмоне</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Зажим для денег</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Ремни</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ремешки для часов</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-5">Кардхолдеры</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-6">Браслеты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-7">Обложки для<br> документов</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-8">Подарочные <br>комплекты</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container-img-fluid">
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="card-block-top">
      <div class="card-txt-block">
        <a href="portmone.html"><img src="full/1.jpg">
          <p class="card-description__1">Full</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-txt-block">
        <a href="space-saving.html"><img src="2.jpg">
          <p class="card-description__1">Space-saving</p>
        </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2"></div>
   <div id="tabs-3"></div>
   <div id="tabs-4"></div>
   <div id="tabs-5"></div>
```

Не понимаю как сюда вставить row, col и т.д. + как это будет влиять на адаптив.
В документации BS4 нашел tabs, но как я понял, результата они не дадут, тот который мне нужен ... или я ошибаюсь.
Что посоветуете ?

Comment: ну если у вам bootstrap там же есть tabs их и юзайте

Comment: @Санитариум дело в том, что эти табы нужно внизу расположить, не пойму как стили переопределить чтобы они внизу отображались (табы)

Comment: если надо просто навигацию перенести в низ до достаточно будет просто управление поместить в самый низ , вот так :  [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OarJPg?editors=1000)